# Cucumber with dependency steps

Tags: gradle, dependency-injection, cucumber

I'm trying to execute cucumber tests using gradle in a project ("ACTUAL_PROJECT"), but it has dependency of other project ("DEPENDENCY"). The tests of "ACTUAL_PROJECT" use some core features and steps of "DEPENDENCY".

The problem is that the execution detect undefined steps (from the dependency) and skip the steps from the actual project.

```
17 Steps (5 skipped, 12 undefined)
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
```

build.gradle

```
project(':ACTUAL_PROJECT') {
    dependencies {
        testCompile project(':DEPENDENCY').sourceSets.test.output
    }

    configurations {
        cucumberRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
        testCompile.transitive = false
    }

    task integrationTest(dependsOn: [testClasses, compileTestJava]) {
        doLast {
            return javaexec {
                main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
                classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.test.output
                args = ["-g",
                    "xx.xxx.xxxx.ACTUAL_PROJECT.steps",
                    "classpath: xx.xxx.xxxx.DEPENDENCY.steps",
                    "src/test/resources/features/ ",
                    "-p",
                    "pretty"]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks